# Python: sliding window of variable width

Tags: python, sliding-window

I'm writing a program in Python that's processing some data generated during experiments, and it needs to estimate the slope of the data. I've written a piece of code that does this quite nicely, but it's horribly slow (and I'm not very patient). Let me explain how this code works:

1) It grabs a small piece of data of size dx (starting with 3 datapoints)

2) It evaluates whether the difference (i.e. |y(x+dx)-y(x-dx)| ) is larger than a certain minimum value (40x std. dev. of noise)

3) If the difference is large enough, it will calculate the slope using OLS regression. If the difference is too small, it will increase dx and redo the loop with this new dx

4) This continues for all the datapoints

[See updated code further down]

For a datasize of about 100k measurements, this takes about 40 minutes, whereas the rest of the program (it does more processing than just this bit) takes about 10 seconds. I am certain there is a much more efficient way of doing these operations, could you guys please help me out?

Thanks

EDIT:

Ok, so I've got the problem solved by using only binary searches, limiting the number of allowed steps by 200. I thank everyone for their input and I selected the answer that helped me most.

FINAL UPDATED CODE:

```
def slope(self, data, time):
    (wave1, wave2) = wt.dwt(data, "db3")
    std = 2*np.std(wave2)
    e = std/0.05
    de = 5*std
    N = len(data)
    slopes = np.ones(shape=(N,))
    data2 = np.concatenate((-data[::-1]+2*data[0], data, -data[::-1]+2*data[N-1]))
    time2 = np.concatenate((-time[::-1]+2*time[0], time, -time[::-1]+2*time[N-1]))
    for n in xrange(N+1, 2*N):     
        left = N+1
        right = 2*N
        for i in xrange(200):
            mid = int(0.5*(left+right))
            diff = np.abs(data2[n-mid+N]-data2[n+mid-N])
            if diff >= e:
                if diff < e + de:  
                    break
                right = mid - 1
                continue
            left = mid + 1
        leftlim = n - mid + N
        rightlim = n + mid - N
        y = data2[leftlim:rightlim:int(0.05*(rightlim-leftlim)+1)]
        x = time2[leftlim:rightlim:int(0.05*(rightlim-leftlim)+1)]
        xavg = np.average(x)
        yavg = np.average(y)
        xlen = len(x)
        slopes[n-N] = (np.dot(x,y)-xavg*yavg*xlen)/(np.dot(x,x)-xavg*xavg*xlen)
    return np.array(slopes)
```

Comment: Doesn't it get stuck at end, where you cannot increase `i` anymore (if absolute value is less than `e`)?

Comment: As for the original question, I would see if `i` can be reduced slightly instead of getting reset to `0` every loop. I first thought decreasing by one would be enough, but it doesn't work in all cases.

Comment: Can I ask what windows does? From what I can see nothing is done with it.

Comment: Profile your code to see where it's spending most of it time. This will tell you what to optimize.

Comment: Can you do this with slicing instead? For numpy arrays and python lists x[0:2N] for x of length N is the same as x[0:N], that should remove one test (whatever built-in test python does is probably faster).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comments suggest that you need to find a better method to estimate i<sub>k+1</sub> given i<sub>k</sub>. No knowledge of values in `data` would yield to the naive algorithm:

At each iteration for `n`, leave `i` at previous value, and see if the `abs(data[start]-data[end])` value is less than `e`. If it is, leave `i` at its previous value, and find your new one by incrementing it by 1 as you do now. If it is greater, or equal, do a binary search on `i` to find the appropriate value. You can possibly do a binary search forwards, but finding a good candidate upper limit without knowledge of `data` can prove to be difficult. This algorithm won't perform worse than your current estimation method.

If you know that `data` is kind of smooth (no sudden jumps, and hence a smooth plot for all `i` values) and monotonically increasing, you can replace the binary search with a search backwards by decrementing its value by 1 instead.

Comment: Thanks vhallac, I've tried your proposed methods: the new code resulted in a significant speed gain, but still it is too slow :(

Comment: You probably need to continue the profiling. You identify the slowest part, speed it up, identify the next one, etc. If it is still estimation of `i`, you'll need to analyze the values (both `data` and `i`) more closely, and find a better estimator.

Comment: What I did so far is ditching the increments of i and go for the binary search right from the start. This algorithm is about 10x faster than the old one (measured on some test data only), but seems to be prone to getting locked into infinite loops. I've updated the code in my first post

Answer (score 0):

How to optimize this will depend on some properties of your data, but here are some ideas:

1. Have you tried profiling the code? Using one of the [Python profilers](http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) can give you some useful information about what's taking the most time. Often, a piece of code you've just written will have one biggest bottleneck, and it's not always obvious which piece it is; profiling lets you figure that out and attack the main bottleneck first.
2. Do you know what typical values of `i` are? If you have some idea, you can speed things up by starting with `i` greater than 0 (as @vhallac noted), or by increasing `i` by larger amounts — if you often see big values for `i`, increase `i` by 2 or 3 at a time; if the distribution of `i`s has a long tail, try doubling it each time; etc.
3. Do you need all the data when doing the least squares regression? If that function call is the bottleneck, you may be able to speed it up by using only some of the data in the range. Suppose, for instance, that at a particular point, you need `i` to be 200 to see a large enough (above-noise) change in the data. But you may not need all 400 points to get a good estimate of the slope — just using 10 or 20 points, evenly spaced in the `start:end` range, may be sufficient, and might speed up the code a lot.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. From profiling I learned that the regression takes mere seconds, by far most of the execution time is taken up by the nested loop. The value for `i` ranges between 3 and 1500 typically. My main problem is that the data behaves a bit like an exp(-x) function, so starting with a steep slope, followed by strong curvature finishing with a very gentle slope. But I'll give it a try using a different increment of `i`

Answer (score 0):

I work with Python for similar analyses, and have a few suggestions to make. I didn't look at the details of your code, just to your problem statement:

> 1) It grabs a small piece of data of size dx (starting with 3
>   datapoints)
>
> 2) It evaluates whether the difference (i.e. |y(x+dx)-y(x-dx)| ) is
>   larger than a certain minimum value (40x std. dev. of noise)
>
> 3) If the difference is large enough, it will calculate the slope
>   using OLS regression. If the difference is too small, it will increase
>   dx and redo the loop with this new dx
>
> 4) This continues for all the datapoints

I think the more obvious reason for slow execution is the LOOPING nature of your code, when perhaps you could use the VECTORIZED (array-based operations) nature of Numpy.

For step 1, instead of taking pairs of points, you can perform directly `data[3:] - data[-3:] and get all the differences in a single array operation;

For step 2, you can use the result from array-based tests like `numpy.argwhere(data > threshold)` instead of testing every element inside some loop;

Step 3 sounds conceptually wrong to me. You say that if the difference is too small, it will increase `dx`. But if the difference is small, the resulting slope would be small because it IS actually small. Then, getting a small value is the right result, and artificially increasing `dx` to get a "better" result might not be what you want. Well, it might actually be what you want, but you should consider this. I would suggest that you calculate the slope for a fixed `dx` across the whole data, and then take the resulting array of slopes to select your regions of interest (for example, using `data_slope[numpy.argwhere(data_slope > minimum_slope)]`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: About step 3 first: I've fixed the problem you described by putting a limit on the width of the window (say 10% of the datasize). --- I've been thinking about using vectors to deal with the datapoints all in once, but I haven't had much success so far. But I'll give it a try using the `numpy.argwhere()` function. Thanks!